# Using groupby to interpolate longitude/latitude coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have a dataframe with sets of longitude/latitude values, where each set of coordinates behave linearly. The coordinates in each set all have a common index value, so I've been trying to figure out a way to use groupby and apply interpolation in order to obtain a greater abundance of data. Here is my data (simplified):

```
    Longitude   Latitude
t                   
0   40          70
0   41          71
0   42          72
0   43          73
1   120         10
1   121         12
1   122         14
1   123         16
... ...         ...
```

For this instance, each set has 4 coordinates, and I want to interpolate each set to have a specific number of coordinates, say 8. This is what I've tried so far. The function works by returning a dataframe with interpolated numbers, but I'm not sure how to use it in conjunction with groupby. How should I word the command, or is there a better method?

```
from scipy import interpolate

def interpolate(lon,lat):
      #convert coordinates into array
      x=np.asarray(lon)
      y=np.asarray(lat)
      #generates interpolation function based on coordinates
      f=interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='linear')
      #set of numbers stretching from minimum to maximum longitude
      xnew=np.linspace(min(lon), max(lon), num=8, endpoint=True)
      #apply interpolation function to obtain interpolated latitude
      df={'lon':xnew,'lat':f(xnew)}
      df=pd.DataFrame(df)
      return df

df.groupby(level=0).apply(interpolate(df['Longitude'],df['Latitude']))
```

Comment: Spatiality is immutable. You cannot make it mere numbers and interpolate.  Though mathematically doable, it is use of geography the wrong way.

Comment: You are correct that the use of geography is incorrect. However, I've simplified this problem to try and understand how to preform groupby with a function that needs two values and returns two values.

Comment: Suggestions #1 if you import `scipy.interpolate`, then use another name for your function #2 do `groupby('t')` #3 in `apply`, your need `apply(lambda df: interpolate(df['Longitude'],df['Latitude']))`